# Finding limit for the function

Tags: calculus, limits

I have problem with showing that the limit of the following function

$$\frac{
 \sqrt{\frac{3 \pi}{2n}} -
 \int_0^{\sqrt 6}(
 1-\frac{x^2}{6}
 +\frac{x^4}{120})^ndx}{\frac{3}{20}\frac 1n \sqrt{\frac{3 \pi}{2n}}}$$

equal to $1$, with $n \to \infty$.

Comment: For what it counts, Wolphram alpha gives 


http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?_=1325710547024&i=integral%5b(+1-%7bx%5e2%7d%2f%7b6%7d+%2b%7bx%5e4%7d%2f%7b120%7d)%5en%5d%2c+0%3Cx%3Csqrt(6)&fp=1&incTime=true


$\int_0^{\sqrt 6}(1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120})^ndx= \sqrt6 F_1(\frac{1}{2};-n,-n; -\frac{3}{2};\frac{3i}{5i+\sqrt5},-\frac{3i}{-5i+\sqrt5})$

Where $F_1(a;b_1,b_2;c;x,y)$ is Appell Hypergeometric function of two variables.

Comment: I thought that the definite integral could be treated as a constant but Nikhil Bellarykar clarified that it would be a function of n, so using L'Hospital rule is not possible.

Comment: Wolphram alpha further gives the series expansion of the Appell function at $n=\infty$ as ${(\frac{3}{10})^n}(\frac{64n^2+56n}{27}+1)$. 

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=F1%281%2F2%3B%E2%88%92n%2C%E2%88%92n%2C%E2%88%923%2F2%2C+3i%2F%285i%2B%E2%88%9A5%29%2C%E2%88%923i%2F%28%E2%88%925i%2B%E2%88%9A5%29%29+series+
But if we plug in this value in the original function, the answer does not come as 1. Am I wrong to simply plug in this value? maybe. Even if I just try to plug in a simple series expansion, the result does not seem to be 1. Someone please clarify what is missing from my approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** First note that for $x\in[0,\sqrt{6}]$, $1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}$ monotonically decreases from $1$ to $\frac{3}{10}$ and that
$$
1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}\le1-\frac{x^2}{9}\le e^{-x^2/9}\tag{1}
$$
You might try the change of variables $x\mapsto x/\sqrt{n}$ so that
$$
\int_0^\sqrt{6}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}\right)^n\;\mathrm{d}x
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^\sqrt{6n}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6n}+\frac{x^4}{120n^2}\right)^n\;\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
$$
and $(1)$ then says that for $x\in[0,\sqrt{6n}]$
$$
\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6n}+\frac{x^4}{120n^2}\right)^n\le e^{-x^2/9}\tag{3}
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^\sqrt{6n}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6n}+\frac{x^4}{120n^2}\right)^n\;\mathrm{d}x
&\le\int_a^\infty e^{-x^2/9}\;\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\frac{9}{2a}e^{-a^2/9}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Notice that the integrand on the right in $(2)$ tends to $e^{-x^2/6}$, so consider
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6n}+\frac{x^4}{120n^2}\right)^n
&=e^{-x^2/6}\exp\left(n\log\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6n}+\frac{x^4}{120n^2}\right)+\frac{x^2}{6}\right)\\
&=e^{-x^2/6}\left(1-\frac{x^4}{180n}-\frac{10x^6-x^8}{64800n^2}+O\left(\frac{x^8}{n^3}\right)\right)\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Applying $(5)$ to $(2)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
&\left|\;\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^\sqrt{6n}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6n}+\frac{x^4}{120n^2}\right)^n\;\mathrm{d}x
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/6}\left(1-\frac{x^4}{180n}-\frac{10x^6-x^8}{64800n^2}\right)\;\mathrm{d}x\;\right|\\
&\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^{\log(n)} e^{-x^2/6}O\left(\frac{x^8}{n^3}\right)\;\mathrm{d}x\\
&+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{\log(n)}^\sqrt{6n}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6n}+\frac{x^4}{120n^2}\right)^n\;\mathrm{d}x
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{\log(n)}^\infty e^{-x^2/6}\left|1-\frac{x^4}{180n}-\frac{10x^6-x^8}{64800n^2}\right|\;\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\sqrt{6}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}\right)^n\;\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^\sqrt{6n}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6n}+\frac{x^4}{120n^2}\right)^n\;\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/6}\left(1-\frac{x^4}{180n}-\frac{10x^6-x^8}{64800n^2}\right)\;\mathrm{d}x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{3\pi}{2n}}\left(1-\frac{3}{20n}+\frac{11}{160n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Truly amazing effort!

Comment: @David: I was really hoping that there was a simpler solution. If the instructor shows you a simpler solution, please post it here.

Comment: Sure. Thank you very much, robjohn.

Comment: @robjohn: you have interesting proof. But how to show that there are no other terms with $1/n$, $1/n^2$ so on?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see it. Could you elaborate please. Also, how to be in the situation when  one would like to get result with $O(1/n^2)$ or $O(1/n)$. Which argument one should use to show that there are finite number of terms? Thank you.

Comment: @robjohn: I've got how binomial theorem works for the integral $\int_0^{\sqrt {6n}}(1-t^2/(6n)+t^4/(120n^2))$. But when we represented as an integral  $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/6}\left(1-\frac{x^4}{180n}-\frac{10x^6-x^8}{6480n^2}\right)\;\mathrm{d}x$, we multiplied by the series of exponential function. And the series is infinite, so there are infinite number of terms for each $(1/n)^k, k=0,1,2,3, \ldots$. How to show that there are infinite number of terms, say with $(1/n^3)$? Or, it follows just from the equality of the two integrals? Thank you.

Comment: @Aleks.K: I have deleted my previous comment which was in error. Look back at equation $(5)$:
$$
\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6n}+\frac{x^4}{120n^2}\right)^n
=e^{-x^2/6}\exp\left(n\log\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6n} +\frac{x^4}{120n^2}\right)+\frac{x^2}{6}\right)
$$
This is simply rewriting things in terms of $\log$ and $\exp$. Using the first three terms of the power series for $\log(1+u)$, where $u=-\frac{z^2}{6n}+\frac{x^4}{120n^2}$ gives

Comment: @Aleks.K: 
$$
\begin{align}
&e^{-x^2/6}\exp\left(n\left(u-\frac12u^2+\frac13u^2 +O\left(u^4\right)\right)+\frac{x^2}{6}\right)\\
&=e^{-x^2/6}\exp\left(n\left(-\frac{x^2}{6n} -\frac{x^4}{180n^2}-\frac{x^6}{6480n^3} +O\left(\frac{x^8}{n^4}\right)\right)+\frac{x^2}{6}\right)\\
&=e^{-x^2/6}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{x^4}{180n} -\frac{x^6}{6480n^2}+O\left(\frac{x^8}{n^3}\right) +\frac{x^2}{6}\right)\\
&=e^{-x^2/6}\exp\left(-\frac{x^4}{180n}-\frac{x^6}{6480n^2} +O\left(\frac{x^8}{n^3}\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @Aleks.K: Then using the fist three terms for $\exp(u)$ where $u=-\frac{x^4}{180n}-\frac{x^6}{6480n^2} +O\left(\frac{x^8}{n^3}\right)$ gives
$$
e^{-x^2/6}\left(1-\frac{x^4}{180n}-\frac{10x^6-x^8}{64800n^2} +O\left(\frac{x^8}{n^3}\right)\right)
$$
Does that answer your question?

Comment: robjohn: Thank you. But it does not explained why we have the finite number of terms for each summand $1/n, 1/n^2, ...$

Comment: @Aleks.K: If you are computing a power series $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots$ where $x=\frac{b_1}{n}+\frac{b_2}{n^2}+\frac{b_3}{n^3}+\dots$, the $a_kx^k$ term is only going to have terms with $\frac1n$ raised at least to the power $k$. So to get *all* the terms larger than $\frac{1}{n^4}$, we just need to include $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$ since all the terms $a_4x^4+a_5x^5+a_6x^6+\dots$ will have $\frac1n$ raised at least to the power 4.